# jQuery FullCalendar event deletion by dragging

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, jquery-events

I have this code:

```
eventDragStop: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
}
```

But I'm stuck there. I'd like to be able to drag the event over a div with the class name of "event-delete" and the event is deleted.

I've tried several ways to identify if the event is being dragged over the delete div to no avail. The solution above seems to partially be working. The event trigger is working but freezes any dragged element in place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just customize this and throw it in your js.

```
        $('#calendar').children('.fc-content').children().append('<div id="calendarTrash" style="float: right; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span></div>');

    //listens for drop event
    $("#calendarTrash").droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        drop: function(event, ui) { 
            if ( dragged && ui.helper && ui.helper[0] === dragged[0] ) {
                var event = dragged[1];
                var answer = confirm("Delete Event?")
                if (answer)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'/employees/removeevent?id='+event.id,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        async: false,
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                        {
                            //console.log(xhr.status);
                            //console.log(thrownError);
                        },
                        success: function()
                        {
                            calendar.fullCalendar( 'removeEvents' , event.id  );
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });

        eventDragStart: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 
            dragged = [ ui.helper[0], event ];
        },
```

Comment: I'be been working with this but I can't seem to get my event id. In your example, what is `dragged`? How do I get my event id?

Comment: sorry this was a long time ago. "dragged" was just an array that I was using to store the different parts of the Drag Event that I wanted. You probably don't need everything. I think I was trying to do something to fit my specific needs there.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used fullcalendar, but if I remember correct `ui` gives you access to the actual element that is being dragged, correct?  If that's the case then you can get the coords of the dragged element and the coords of the delete div and check if they're within each other.

jQuery grants access to coordinates relative to the page through `.offset()`.  The coords only give `top` and `left`, however right and bottom can be calculated using the element's height and width.

(untested but the general idea)

```
var isElemOverDiv = function(draggedItem, dropArea) {
   // Prep coords for our two elements
   var a = $(draggedItem).offset();
   a.right = $(draggedItem).outerWidth() + a.left;
   a.bottom = $(draggedItem).outerHeight() + a.top;

   var b = $(dropArea).offset();
   a.right = $(dropArea).outerWidth() + b.left;
   a.bottom = $(dropArea).outerHeight() + b.top;

   // Compare
   if (a.left >= b.left
       && a.top >= b.top
       && a.right <= b.right
       && a.bottom <= b.bottom) { return true; }
   return false;
}

eventDragStop: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
    if (isElemOverDiv(ui, $('div.event-delete'))) {
        calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
    }
}
```

The one tricky part here is `isElemOverDiv(ui, ...`.  I don't recall what the value of `ui` is.  You may need to change that to something like `ui.element` to get the actual reference to the element.

Comment: Okay I've played around with the code but I'm stuck on something. When an event is dragged, no matter where it's dropped, the event freezes in place and is stuck until another event is created.

Comment: Stone I've tried every bit of ui I can think of as well as different position algorithms to no avail. Anything even remotely plausible would help at this point!

Comment: Ok, I'll help T.Stone's answer to make it sharper. first of all, all your events must have 'id'. second, the 'isElemOverDiv' function should be written like this:

var isElemOverDiv = function(draggedItem, dropArea) {
  var dragged = $(draggedItem)[0].offset;

  var b = $(dropArea);
  var limitX = parseInt(b.offset().left) + parseInt(b.outerWidth());
  var limitY = parseInt(b.offset().top) + parseInt(b.outerHeight());

  // Compare
  if ( limitY >=   parseInt(dragged.top) 
   && limitX >=   parseInt(dragged.left) ) 
  { 
   return true; 
  }
  return false;
 }

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on T.Stone answer.

- All events must have '**id**'.

  ```
  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  ...
  eventDragStop: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view) { 
                 //console.log(event.id);
                  if (isElemOverDiv(ui, $('div#delete-events'))) {
                      calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
                  }
              }
  });


  //And an helper function:


  var isElemOverDiv = function(draggedItem, dropArea) {
          var dragged = $(draggedItem)[0].offset;

          var b = $(dropArea);
          var limitX = parseInt(b.offset().left) + parseInt(b.outerWidth());
          var limitY = parseInt(b.offset().top) + parseInt(b.outerHeight());

          // Compare
          if ( limitY >=   parseInt(dragged.top) 
              && limitX >=   parseInt(dragged.left) ) 
          { 
              return true; 
          }
          return false;
      }
  ```

It worked perfectly for me!

Many thanks to T.Stone for his lead idea :)

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the external-dragging demo and posted the code to the comments on http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=550. Hope it helps.

The code allows the events to be dragged off of and back on to the calendar.

I was using Chrome for testing.

Answer (score 0):

i tell you drop: function(event, ui) 
ui :: ui holds an empty object. Before version 2.1, the jQuery UI object. :)
and work then jsEvent :)
sn :

```
eventDragStop: function(event, jsEvent, ui, view) {

       if (isElemOverDiv(jsEvent, $('div#external-events'))) {

           console.log(isElemOverDiv(jsEvent, $('div#external-events')));
           $('.calendario').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);
       }
   }

  var isElemOverDiv = function(draggedItem, dropArea) {
  var p = dropArea;
  var position = p.position();
  console.log("EL DROP AREA left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top);
  console.log('draggedItem.pageY ', draggedItem.clientX, draggedItem.pageY);
  if (draggedItem.clientX >= position.left && draggedItem.pageY >= position.top) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
```

}